# Mail keeps crashing on my os 10.11

Tags: macos

My OS X  El Capitan mail app crashes immediately when I click on it. Why is this happening?

I am using Windows 10 to send this email

Comment: If you make a new user account, does Mail crash there? (i.e. you might need to perform some basic troubleshooting else we all play 20 questions...) what if you disconnect from the network and reboot and open mail?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. Turned out it was OpenPGP. Went to their website, upgraded to the beta. Issue stopped.

Also, you might want to check for other Mail plugins.